# Adding extra state to itertools.product

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have taken a look at itertools.permutations and combinations, but I don't think they will work for my issue.

Basically, I am looking to create a list of all possible permutations of a given string with a defined length (greater than the amount of elements).

Basically, I would like to have three possible states, 0, 1, or don't care [0,1,'*'].

I had hoped to do something like:

```
s = list(itertools.product(('0','1','*'), repeat=8))
```

However, product doesn't seem to like more than 2 parameters in its first parameter.

If I try to scale up the permutations or combinations (ie greater than the amount of combinations) I end up with an empty array returned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `product doesn't seem to like more than 2 parameters in its first parameter.` the code you posted works fine for me, returning eight-item tuples.

Comment: The code you posted works for me too on Python 2.7.

Comment: Interesting, I couldn't get it to work locally, then I formatted it nicely for posting here...and I apparently got rid of my typo.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = list(itertools.product(('0','1','*'), repeat=8))
>>> len(s)
6561
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/WAfsi).